# Unresolved @sample in Kotlin docs

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, documentation, javadoc

When I inspect the Kotlin docs, for example `Collections.map(...)` Intellij Idea can't resolve the reference mentioned in docs.

What should I add to my project to make it work?

[image]

[image: docs]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19119. Feel free to subscribe by pressing the star in Youtrack.