# Is there a way to open Kotlin samples in IntelliJ?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

When using `Kotlin 1.4.32` in `IntelliJ 2021.1.1`, there are a lot of `@sample` implementations in Kotlin's Kdoc. However, these are not clickable in IntelliJ.

For example, the `kotlin.properties.Delegates#observable` has a reference to an unresolved `samples.properties.Delegates.observableDelegate` sample.

The `stdlib` samples can be found here https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/stdlib/samples, but I haven't figured a way to get the samples on the classpath so that I can click these in IntelliJ.

Comment: Currently it's not supported. Please vote/watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-8414.

Comment: Thanks! Shame the samples are effectively are useless as one cannot open them :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unresolved @sample in Kotlin docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63078323/unresolved-sample-in-kotlin-docs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alexey Belkov from JetBrains said in the comments, it's not supported in IntelliJ right now.

They are not "effectively useless" however, because the samples are executable from the online documentation. For example, here's [`map()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html).

Comment: in the [linked issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-8414) it says that the jar with the samples can be downloaded separately. any hints on how to do that?